# Check two series are equal with a condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have two series and want to check if they are equal with a condition on the combination between 'a' and 'b' is acceptable

```
first = pd.Series(['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
second = pd.Series(['A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'K'])
```

expected output :

```
0  True
1  True
2  False
3  True
4  False
```

So far I know `eq` can compare the two series but I am not sure how to include the condition

```
def helper(s1, s2):
    return s1.str.lower().eq(s2.str.lower())
```

Comment: use `numpy.bitwise_or`

Comment: You should consider using [`Series.str.casefold()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.casefold.html) instead of `Series.str.lower()`.

Comment: @AMC thanks for bring this to my attention. I've been doing this stuff for almost a decade now and didn't know about `casefold` and the pitfalls of `lower`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use bitwise logic operations to include your additional logic.

So that's:

```py
condition_1 = first.str.casefold().eq(second.str.casefold())
condition_2 = first.str.casefold().isin(['a', 'b']) & second.str.casefold().isin(['a', 'b'])
result =  condition_1 | condition_2
```

Or with numpy:

```py
condition_1 = first.str.casefold().eq(second.str.casefold())
condition_2 = numpy.bitwise_and(
    first.str.casefold().isin(['a', 'b']),
    second.str.casefold().isin(['a', 'b'])
)
result =  numpy.bitwise_or(condition_1, condition_2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace` to map all `a` to `b`:

```
def transform(s):
    return s.str.lower().replace({'a':'b'})

transform(first).eq(transform(second))
```

Comment: A very minor point, but I think it might be better to remove the second `str` in your transform function. The reason being that as written, this would alter e.g., "aa" to "bb" and that *might* not be desired.

Comment: @PaulH yes, it shouldn’t be there thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify an "ascii_distance" as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

s1 = pd.Series(['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
s2 = pd.Series(['A', 'A', 'b', 'C', 'F'])

def helper(s1, s2, ascii_distance):
    s1_processed = [ord(c1) for c1 in s1.str.lower()]
    s2_processed = [ord(c2) for c2 in s2.str.lower()]

    print(f'ascii_distance = {ascii_distance}')
    print(f's1_processed = {s1_processed}')
    print(f's2_processed = {s2_processed}')

    result = []
    for i in range(len(s1)):
        result.append((abs(s1_processed[i] - s2_processed[i]) <= ascii_distance))

    return result

ascii_distance = 2
print(helper(s1, s2, ascii_distance))
```

Output:

```
ascii_distance = 2
s1_processed = [97, 97, 98, 99, 100]
s2_processed = [97, 97, 98, 99, 102]
[True, True, True, True, True]
```